How to use PySpark to read SQLite db files
I am new to PySpark and I am learning to read a local SQLite db file using PySpark in Jupyter notebook. I am using PySpark 3.5.1. The db file and the notebook were in the same folder. I used the following code
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName('Ops') \
    .config("spark.jars", "mysql-connector-j-8.4.0.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format('jdbc') \
    .options(url='activities.db', dbtable='activities', driver='com.mysql.jdbc.Driver') \
    .load()

I had the following error message.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IllegalArgumentException                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [16], line 3
      1 df = spark.read.format('jdbc') \
      2     .options(url='activities.db', dbtable='activities', driver='com.mysql.jdbc.Driver') \
----> 3     .load()

File ~/anaconda3/envs/spark/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py:314, in DataFrameReader.load(self, path, format, schema, **options)
    312     return self._df(self._jreader.load(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
    313 else:
--> 314     return self._df(self._jreader.load())

File ~/anaconda3/envs/spark/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py:1322, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1316 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1317     self.command_header +\
   1318     args_command +\
   1319     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1321 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1322 return_value = get_return_value(
   1323     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1325 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1326     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):

File ~/anaconda3/envs/spark/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py:185, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    181 converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)
    182 if not isinstance(converted, UnknownException):
    183     # Hide where the exception came from that shows a non-Pythonic
    184     # JVM exception message.
--> 185     raise converted from None
    186 else:
    187     raise

IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The driver could not open a JDBC connection. Check the URL: activities.db

How should I address the problem? Thank you!

Is url='activities.db' correct? I would've thought it'd be url='jdbc:sqlite:activities.db' instead.

@Doot I also tried url='jdbc:sqlite:activities.db'. It did not work either

Hmm, maybe driver='org.sqlite.JDBC' instead of 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'? I see you use a mysql .jar as well. https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc shows 2 dependency jars: sqlite-jdbc-3.46.0.0.jar and slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar.
Other things to verify would be the path to the database (could try an absolute path instead of just the file name) and the .jar being correct.
